# Is Non-linear Constrained Optimal Exact Cover NP-Hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, optimization, partition-problem, covering-problems

Playing around I ran into a problem which looks like a Exact Set Covering / Partition Problem, but I am unable to find a reduction to categorize the complexity of the problem, despite it looks NP-Hard. I will informally state the problem and some of the properties, since describing the problem as a whole would be too lengthy.

> #### **Non-linear Constrained Optimal Exact Cover**
>
> Consider a finite set $C=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ of elements and a vector $\mathbf{w}=\{w_j ~|~ j\in C\}$ of associated weights. 
>   The collection $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots, s_n | s_i\subset C\}$ contains every subset of combinations of elements of $C$ **that fulfills:**  $$f(\mathbf{w}_{s_i})\ge 0, \forall s_i\in S;\quad \text{ where } \mathbf{w}_{s_i}=\{w_j ~|~ j\in s_i\}. $$ 
>   Find the subcollection ${S}^{*}$ of $S$ such that
>
> ($i$) each element in $C$ is contained in exactly one subset of ${S}^{*}$
>
> ($ii$) $g(S^*)=\sum\limits_{i=1,\ldots,n} g(\mathbf{w}_{s_i})$ is maximized.
>
> **Example**: 
>   $C=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4\}$.
>
> Given the weights, the non linear constraint $f(\mathbf{w_{s_i}})\ge 0$ implies:
>   $$S=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,3,4\}\}$$
>   having each subset $s_i\in S$:
>   $$\{g(\mathbf{w_{s_i}}) ~|~ s_i\in S\}=\{4,2,1,5,2,7,8,2,3\}.$$
>   **Solution**: $S^*=\{\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\},$ since each of the elements of $C$ is contained in exactly one subset of $S^*$ and $g(S^*)$ is the maximum possible.

Note that the [Minimum Exact Cover Problem](https://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node147.html) is related but deals with a different objective function (minimize the cardinality of the set) and the general description of the problem does not constrain the subsets that can appear in an instance for S (unlike this problem).

My feeling is that the problem is NP-Hard, since as increasing the size of $C$, the possible set of partitions increase quickly ([Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)). However, I do understand that the reduction in the feasible space may vary the complexity.

My goal is to find the conditions on the functions such that the
problem remains NP-Hard or, if none if it is NP-hard for any pair besides the trivial functions. I have been working a bit into that, but this is not my field of expertise and I am suspicious that a similar work has been done or that a reduction in trivial for expert eyes or at least a categorization of the problem.

---

> **Notes**
>
> - $ ~ f$ and $g$ are non linear functions that depends on the
>     partition. It is hard to define them hereby, but they aim to
>     evaluate the subset similarity, e.g., $f(\mathbf{w}_{s_i})\ge 0$ ensure
>     that the elements weights are similar enough among each other.
> - For any instance of the problem there exists at least one feasible
>     partition. The partition that includes each element in a subset
>     ${S}^{'}=\{\{1\},\{2\},\ldots,\{m\}\}$ is feasible (fulfills
>     condition ($i$)), but it may not be optimal.
> - Clearly, there are some functions for which the problem seems
>     trivial, i.e., if the constraints are $f(\mathbf{w}_{s_i})=-|\mathbf{w}_{s_i}|+1 \ge 0$ then
>     only the partition
>     $S^{'}$ is feasible and then the solution
>     can be obtained in O(1).

Comment: Yes, I can understand the problem now.  So your question is, for what classes of pairs of functions $(f,g)$ is the resulting problem NP-hard?

Comment: Right, the question would be which are the restrictions on the class of functions I shall be looking at to make sure that complexity remains NP-Hard or not, and why? If that makes sense... I have a family of functions pretty particular and I want to know what should I pay attention to?

Comment: That's a pretty open-ended question, and can probably be answered only if there happens to be someone out there who just happens to have studied your problem (or something equivalent).  You _might_ get more traction if you, say, give a particular $(f, g)$ pair and ask whether the problem is NP-hard for that pair.  Or, ask whether someone can show it is NP-hard for _any_ pair.

Comment: It now says "or, if none if it is NP-hard for any pair besides the trivial functions."  I'm confused by this.  For what trivial functions is it NP-hard?  Secondly, I noticed you added a bounty.  I'd guess that to get an answer you'll need to set a more specific goal.  E.g., "show that for some pair (f, g) is is NP-hard.

Comment: In my notes, you can find a function for which the solution is trivial, i.e., for which the solution is not NP-Hard but a trivial solution (Please read the 3rd bullet point).

Regarding the second point is that I deliberately do not know which function I have there.